# Jooq: Postgres jsonb column to byte[] instead of JSONB, then to jackson ObjectNode using binding

Tags: postgresql, binding, byte, jooq, jsonb

Is it possible to map a Postgres `jsonb` column to a `byte[]` instead of `org.jooq.JSONB` and then have a converter that maps `byte[]` to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`?

The issue is that we have the `binaryTransfer` enabled on the Postgres connection, so now the data is read as `byte[]`, then in the binding (which is from `org.jooq.JSONB` to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode`) we convert in to a `String`, then to a `JSONB`, then we call the converter, which creates not needed objects.

Update:

generator configuration:

```java
new ForcedType()
    .withUserType("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode")
    .withBinding("my.pckg.ObjectNodeBinding")
    .withIncludeTypes("jsonb")
```

Binding:

```java
public class ObjectNodeBinding extends AbstractBinding<byte[], ObjectNode> {
```

Generated Table definition for a jsonb field:

```java
public final TableField<MyTableRecord, ObjectNode> DATA = createField(DSL.name("data"), SQLDataType.JSONB.nullable(false), this, "", new ObjectNodeBinding());
```

which results in an error, because the binding expects the type T to be JSONB

Comment: Yes, you can use a custom data type binding for that: 
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-forced-types/codegen-database-forced-types-binding

Comment: We use a custom data type binding, but I still cannot make it work. I updated the description.

Answer (score 0):

Your data type binding must bind to `T=JSONB`, not `T=byte[]`. You don't have to use the fact that jOOQ thinks this is an `org.jooq.JSONB` column in your actual binding code. You can still read `ResultSet.getBytes()` directly. But jOOQ doesn't know what you're putting as `T` and `U` types, so you must at least keep the `T` type as jOOQ expects.

Note that while you have to implement `Binding::converter` to produce a `Converter<JSONB, ObjectNode>`, you don't have to implement it completely, if you're not using it.